# Restore snapshots from 3 node Cassandra cluster to a new 6 node cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am new to cassandra and would like some help on restoring snapshots from 3 node Cassandra cluster to a new 6 node cluster. 
We have few keyspaces and would like to copy data from dev to production.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to use the sstableloader tool that is bundled with Cassandra. You can find it in `%installdir%/bin/sstableloader`.

You will first need to re-create the schema on your new cluster:

1. dump the schema for the keyspace you want to transfer from your original cluster using `cqlsh -e 'DESC KEYSPACE mykeyspace;' > mykeyspace.cql`
2. load it into your new cluster using `cqlsh -f mykeyspace.cql`.
3. (optional) If you new cluster will have a different replication configuration you'll need to modify it manually after loading the schema. (`ALTER KEYSPACE mykeyspace WITH REPLICATION = ...;`)

Once that's done, you can start bulk-loading the SSTables from your keyspace snapshots into the new cluster:

```
sstableloader --nodes 10.0.0.1,10.0.0.2 -f /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml /path/to/mykeyspace/snapshot/
```

Note that this might take a while if you have a lot of data to load. You should also run a full repair on the new cluster afterwards to ensure that the replicas are properly distributed.